# Android Dexguard: How to integrate?

Tags: android, dexguard

I am trying to use [Dexguard](https://www.saikoa.com/dexguard) in order to obfuscate my simple Android Application.

I have followed the integration steps, I.e. adding the `jar` file into the `libs` folder in `Eclipse`.

However, Dexguard does not seem to be integrated into my application.

How do I know if Dexguard has been Integrated?

Is there any additional steps that I need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to put the DexGuard plugin in the `dropins` directory in Eclipse. You can find all the necessary details in the DexGuard manual > Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply eric, however my project doesn't have a dropins directory? Do I also need to run the project in release build, i.e. right click>Android Tools>Export unsigned application package?

Comment: Can you also please provide me with a link to the manual, thanks

Comment: The DexGuard manual is in the DexGuard distribution, starting from DexGuard*/docs/index.html.

Comment: I cannot find the Plugins directory within my eclipse project, do you know where I can find it?

Comment: I does state this in the dexguard docs. The dropins/plugins dir is within your Eclipse installation folder.